# Enable NX-bit in Atom N270 for Acer AOA 150-1570?

Tags: windows-8, bios, acer-aspire-one

I tried looking in the BIOS settings for an NX option but I did not find any. Is there any trick or hidden menu in the BIOS or elsewhere that I can enable the hardware support for NX? Have I missed something or is my computer not capable or running Windows 8 because of the BIOS even after having hardware support?

EDIT: System BIOS is v0.3310 / Insyde H2O Setup Utility Rev 3.5
Options - Information Main Security Boot Exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. The hardware may be present, but it needs to be set up in the BIOS or the UEFI. This is similar to lack of BIOS support for AHCI, which used to be quite common. Especially on less expensive products.

The correct 'trick' would be to phone Acer until they set aside a few engineers to write a new BIOS. Probability of success: Near nill, nada, zilch :(

(And no, do not even try that. Though an email to them mentioning your regret at the lack of this feature and that you need to buy new, potentially non-Acer, hardware to run win8 might just give them an extra nudge to doing things the right way.)

Comment: It turns out that I cannot enable the option via BIOS... but Windows 8 installed seamlessly so I take it NX bit is now enabled.

Comment: In that case your BIOS has no option for it but enables it by default. Good to know for other owners of a Acer 1570. :)